# Adding leading and trailing spaces to uitableview of child class inherited from parent class programmatically using swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to add leading and trailing spaces to tableview embedded in view programmatically. This tableview has constraints been declared in parent class i am trying to override them in child class. I am doing in the following way

```
class TestTableView: BaseTableViewController{

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.lpBaseTableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.lpBaseTableView.contentSize.height)
    self.lpBaseTableView.center = self.view.center
    self.lpBaseTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.lpBaseTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
    self.lpBaseTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true

 }
}
```

After researching few links from stack overflow i am using the above code but there is no change in the table view position as shown below in the image. Please help me out. I am new to swift and iOS
[image: TableView within a view]

Answer (score 1):

Adding a leading and trailing constraints are simple, just give proper constants with respect to the superview and also give top and bottom constraints. Frame and centre is not needed since you're using autolayout here.

```
    lpBaseTableView = UITableView()
    lpBaseTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(lpBaseTableView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        lpBaseTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
        lpBaseTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
        lpBaseTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        lpBaseTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
    ])
```

Comment: ho you are adding your tableview, delete everything and put the above code in viewDidLoad method

Comment: Sorry i am trying to change the constraints of a tableview which is already declared in parent class. Any idea how to change those constraints in child class

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [SnaKit](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit)

```
    import SnapKit

    lpBaseTableView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.center.equalTo(view)
    make.left.equalTo(view.snp.left)
    make.right.equalTo(view.snp.right)
```

Please note that if there is also constraints from Storyboard for same object it could not work properly